# What is the keyword "this" referring to if it is given as an argument

Tags: java, this, keyword

I know when to use the keyword "this" for fields and constructors but I'm not sure when it is passed as an argument

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    public class SimpleGui implements ActionListener {
        JButton button;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SimpleGui gui = new SimpleGui();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        button = new JButton("click me");

        button.addActionListener(this);

        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        button.setText("I've been clicked!");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the current instance of `SimpleGui`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line `button.addActionListener(this);` means:

- Add a listener to actions performed on the `button` object
- Make the listener the current instance of `SimpleGui` within context (`SimpleGui` happens to implement the `ActionListener` interface)

So when the button is clicked, `SimpleGui#actionPerformed` should be invoked.

Comment: So the JButton instance needs another instance - in this case SimpleGui - which implements a Listener

Comment: To better phrase it, the `JButton` instance may use an instance of `ActionListener` to react to actions performed on it. Since `ActionListener` is an interface, you need an instance of a class implementing `ActionListener`. You can add pretty much any class you wish, as the button's listener, as long as it implements `ActionListener`. Note also that you can add multiple listeners!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a button is presses to get a callback, we need to attach a listener to that button, here in your example that is done using following line,

**button.addActionListener(this);**

addActionListener() requires to pass a instance which implements ActionListener interface.

And here SimpleGui is a ActionListener as it implements that interface. Hence in SimpleGui you are writing,

**button.addActionListener(this);**

where this is instance of SimpleGui which implements ActionListener

Answer (score 0):

This is a keyword which means the instance of the class, 
in your class

```
 public class SimpleGui implements ActionListener {
```

`this` is an instance of the **SimpleGui**, it could be as well an object (any) that is implementing the **actionListener**

If you call a method that accepts `this`, it is because
this argument is an object of the SimpleGui class, or even better, is an object (no matter which one) that implements the **ActionListener**.

Comment: yes, I was updating the post, thnxs for the comment any way